# Is it the right time to convert large .net based distributed SOA system into .net Core?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, wcf, asp.net-core, sharepoint-2010

We have a large business solution with some Windows Services, many WCF services,   some SharePoint application and some ASP.NET MVC web applications those have been developed from nearly 10 years back. Currently we are using .net framework 4.0 .

Now we see .net open source platform is getting popular and it seems .net core will be the future of .net. In this situation, should we convert all the applications into .net core right now or we should wait for some more time (may be more than a years).  Is .net core is stable enough for million dollar project's production yet?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *Is it the right time to convert large .net based distributed SOA system into .net Core?* - No

Answer (score 2):

I have googled to find answers and found answers in dotnet platform documentation:

1. You should use .NET Framework for your server application when:
   Your application currently uses .NET Framework (recommendation is to extend instead of migrating)
2. WCF services implementation. Even when there’s a WCF-Client library to consume WCF services from .NET Core, as of June 2016, WCF server implementation is only available on the .NET Framework. This scenario is not part of the current plan for .NET Core but it’s being considered for the future.
3. Workflow related services: Windows Workflow Foundation (WF), Workflow Services (WCF + WF in a single service) and WCF Data Services (formerly known as “ADO.NET Data Services”) are only available on the .NET Framework and there are no plans to bring them to .NET Core.

As we are fully depended on WCF, we can not move to .net core right now(until wcf is is supported in .net core).

But in case of ADO.NET Data Services related feature to use, it must stay in .net framework.

Here is the document [Choosing between .NET Core and .NET Framework for server apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/standard/choosing-core-framework-server)

Answer (score 0):

you can do it and it has a stable version core 1.1, but it has some limitations:
I feel still the Project.json is not perfectly stabilized and some dnx issues upon my experience with it. For complex projects you will have so many references, so it takes more time to build than normal .net framework project and sometimes it fails to map those dependencies correctly if you use a combination of core and .netframework references in project.json. You need to re generate your build scripts and automated test scripts as core apps uses dotnet cmd and u may need to use xunit as is the best unit test framework for testing core apps. But if you want to make use of deploying your apps on non-windows platform in future, you can start migrating now to core 1.1 (stable version) with minimal changes. If you deploy the web apps in Azure, .net core apps has some limitations with framework v4.6. 
 **But has more build in options like:**
strongly typed settings via IOptions, simple configuration and although it provides many built-in middlewares, it also provies a way for injecting your custom logic to request pipeline via custom middlewares, Web apps runs in Kestrel, so that u can run ur app from a console even etc., As migrating doesnt increase ur Productivity. Do it if u strictly need it. You can refer to any msdn article related to it to start https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/index and issues faced with it in: https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues

Comment: I have read in documentations and got my answers (provided below) for our business cases. But Thank you for your answer.

Comment: yes, if your major part of system works on wcf, then wcf migration to core cant be done. But, if needed, still you can migrate those some asp.net mvc apps you have mentioned and has some pros and cons that u can refer to my answer.

Comment: Have you heard of something called paragraphs?